# Custom Random Enumerable?

Tags: c#, random, ienumerable

I have a class `Rectangle` which has a method `RandomPoint` returning a random point within it. It looks like:

```
class Rectangle {
    int W,H;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Point RandomPoint() {
        return new Point(rnd.NextDouble() * W, rnd.NextDouble() * H);
    }
}
```

But I hope it to be a `IEnumerable<Point>` so that I can use `LINQ` on it, e.g. `rect.RandomPoint().Take(10)`.

How to implement it succinctly?

Comment: So, you want to get a set of random points within the rectangle?

Comment: Is `Point` a custom type or a one from the framework or a library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an iterator block:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }

    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Point> RandomPoints(Random rnd)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new Point(rnd.NextDouble() * Width,
                                   rnd.NextDouble() * Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: until today I didn't realize what yield does. BTW, why do you suggest `Rectangle` to receive a `Random` as parameter, rather than maintaining in itself?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan: Because in your code if you create multiple rectangles in a loop they will all generate the same sequence of points.

Comment: but don't they still generate the same sequence, if I use `while(true) { var rnd = new Random(); var rect = new Rectangle(); }`?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan: Yes. That's why you should not create the random object inside the loop. You should create a single random object outside the loop and reuse that same object for all your rectangles.

Answer (score 7):

```
IEnumerable<Point> RandomPoint(int W, int H)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (true)
        yield return new Point(rnd.Next(0,W+1),rnd.Next(0,H+1));
}
```

Comment: Good catch, using `Random.Next(int, int)` instead of `Random.NextDouble()`

Comment: Using `Random.Next(int, int)` can be useful in some situations but note that this code will only generate points that have integral coordinates. The OPs original code will generate any point inside the rectangle, not just points that are integer values. So this might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` could be an option;

```
public IEnumerable<Point> RandomPoint() {
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new Point(rnd.NextDouble() * W, rnd.NextDouble() * H);
    }
```